# ODBCKit framework stopped working on macOS Ventura (13.4)

Tags: swift, macos, odbc

I have an macOS app using ODBCKit to connect to the database via ODBC driver/manager. This setup was working before upgrade to Ventura (13.4) macOS version on this exact same (intel chip) mac book pro.

I have my ODBC manager connection configured properly on my local macine, and testing the DB connection via ODBC FileManager works as expected. When I try to connect to the DB via ODBCKit's ODBCConnection().connect() I receive a following log in my app console:
***SQLConnect***
***SQL Error State:08S01, Native Error Code: 7FF800000001, ODBC Error: [FileMaker][FileMaker] Failed to connect to listener (2)***

So I am suspecting problem with the ODBCKit.framework downloaded from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/odbckit/
Any idea how to fix this to work with the Ventura 13.4 macOS version?